# Media file won't play from the flash drive, playing from HD

Tags: windows-8, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, media

I have a number of media files (avi, mp4) which are working properly and can be played on my PC. (Windows 8)

However when I copy the files to a flash drive (exFAT, fresh formatted) just a few can be played. For the others I get *"Unknown codec or broken file"*

MD5 of the files on hard disk and on flash drive are equal so it shouldn't be a broken file. It shouldn't be a codec problem as I can play the file located on the hard drive.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

UPD: I have to recheck about MD5. Just rechecked one and MD5 was different. It can lead to another question - how can the file copied to flash drive have different MD5...

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the technical background of this story.
But we discovered later that the (chinees) flash drive was a fake one. 
Which did as it was much larger then it really is. 
So when we copied the file of let say 1.5 Gb to the drive it didn't warn that there is no space. But accepted the file. And the OS showed it as it has a size of 1.5 Gb. 
Therefore MD5 was different. And of course it couldn't be played.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the flash drive to NTFS drive and copy the specified files back to the your flash drive and now check whether its playing the media files without any issue.

Comment: Thank You. According to the specifications exFAT looks like a right filesystem. The limits are large.
But I tried NTFS as you suggested.
No difference...